# running npm install on samba share

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, smb

I'm attempting to run `npm install` on a mounted samba share (FreeNAS). The first time I was able to install webpack but all subsequent attempts to install any package fail with `EACCES: permission denied, chown` errors on package.json files in the node_modules directory. (I am able to successfully install packages to normal (non mounted) directories in the file system).

As a regular user I'm able to read and write to the share. However I'm not able to run `chown`. Why does `npm install` try to run chown? How can I successfully install packages?

OS: Linux Mint, node version 10.10.0, npm version 6.4.1

Comment: I wasn't able to resolve this problem. However I switched from npm to yarn and installing worked without issue.